# Javascript, ajax loading external page, redirect breaks links

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am building a chrome extension that loads a real preview of links you click in your search results. I analyze the links that come up, and add a `<base>` url element that handles all relative urls.

However, when I do an ajax request for a pages html, but that page ultimately redirects, my `<base>` element is incorrect because it does not take into account the redirect that happened.

To re-iterate, A user clicks a search result, I send an ajax GET request to that url to receive the pages html. I analyze the link that was clicked, and add an appropriate `<base>` element when I insert the pages html. (There isn't anything else in the DOM other than an iframe of the search results, so the `<base>` element doesn't alter anything else.)

For any situation that doesn't have a redirect, the `<base>` element is always correct and works great.

When I search 'ty' on google, `www.ty.com` redirects to `world.ty.com`. How can I detect the response came from `world.ty.com`?   My `<base>` element ends up with `www.ty.com`

---

I am looking at attaching a window.onerror event that detects a 404 and somehow, I have no idea, corrects the `<base>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot retrieve the final, redirected URL through the `XMLHttpRequest` object. You *can* however, create a workaround for this (replace your current `<base>` tag by the following code):

```
<!--BEFORE linking any content (at the beggining of HEAD / document-->
<script>
document.write('<base href="'+location.href.replace(/"/g,"%22")+'" />');
</script>
```

If you embed your script in the document, either use `CDATA` sections, or add a `\` before the script tag, to prevent your page from incorrectly parsing the JavaScript code.

Example of an implementation:

```
function handleAjaxResponse(html){
  //Searching for `<head>` or `<html>` to insert your HTNL is not reliable:
  // The web master may practice:
  // .. (without html/head tags)..<body> <input value="<head>" /> ....
  html = "<script>" +
   "document.write('<base href=\"'+location.href.replace(/\"/g,'%22')+'\" />')" +
   "<\/script>" + html; //Notice <\/script> !

  //...output html...
}
```

Comment: I'm currently developing functions to parse HTML strings and URLs within this string. See my profile. I expect to have finished these functions within a week.

Comment: well the entire time the address bar is at google's search page. Running location.href returns http://www.google.com/search?etc So I don't think this would work at all.

Comment: See my first statement. Unfortunately, you cannot get the redirected URL through XHR, because the `Location: ...` headers are automatically followed by JavaScript. Another (less reliable) option is trying to detect an absolute URL of a document (eg search for all absolute URLs, and set the base URL to the URL which appears significantly more often than the other URLs.